# CSS grid layout: Keeping horizontal and vertical gutters equal size when resizing

Tags: html, css, css-grid

**What I'd like to do**: I try to achieve a page using CSS grid layout. At full size, vertical and horizontal gutters should be 20px. But if course it has to be responsive. *Precisely, I'd like the horizontal gutter to resize the same way that the vertical one will, to keep the same margin ratios between pictures*.

**My problem**: I tried several options to achieve this. In the code below, I used 1.25em. Why that? My assumption was that, as base font size is by default about 16px, I supposed that 1.25em (20px) should do the trick. But it doesn't work... and I can't find another way to get the desired behaviour. Could you please help with some directions?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1420px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}   
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
/*First section*/
.wide {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;  /* 1420px; */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1.25em;
}
.wide-a {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
/*Second section*/
.composed {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 49.295774647% 1.408450704% 49.295774647%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1.25em auto 1.25em;
}
.composed-a {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}
.composed-b {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.composed-c {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wide">
      <figure class="wide-a">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1420x955" width="">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="composed">
      <figure class="composed-a">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x950" width="">
      </figure>
      <figure class="composed-b">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x490" width="">
      </figure>
      <figure class="composed-c">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x440" width="">
      </figure>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you open to the possibility of using Masonry? I find it easier than CSS grids.

Comment: Yes, Masonry could be an option, no problem.

Comment: I wrote this for another related matter today. You may or may not find it useful. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdadMX

Comment: Could you please add placeholder images so that we can see a full MCVE?

Comment: @TylerH added the placeholders and learned a new acronym in the process!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pixel units, use viewport percentage units. Something like this:

```
grid-gap: 10vmin
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oy7ahgvs/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-gap: 10vmin;  /* NEW */
}

.wide {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1.25em;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  grid-gap: 10vmin;  /* NEW */
}

.composed {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 49.295774647% 1.408450704% 49.295774647%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1.25em;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.composed-a {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  background-color: orange;
}

.composed-b {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.composed-c {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wide">
    <figure class="wide-a">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="composed">
    <figure class="composed-a">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="composed-b">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    </figure>
    <figure class="composed-c">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the spec:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` units**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> - **vw unit** - Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
> - **vh unit** - Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing
>     block.
> - **vmin unit** - Equal to the smaller of `vw` or `vh`.
> - **vmax unit** - Equal to the larger of `vw` or `vh`.

Comment: I try to use your solution but can't really see how the use of vmin will keep horizontal and vertical gutters equals. Do you mean replacing also the gutter column between the two images by a vmin value instead of the actual percentage?

Comment: It's possible I misunderstood your question. When you wrote this: *"I'd like the horizontal gutter to resize the same way that the vertical one will."*, I interpreted that to mean you wanted gutters to scale with screen size.

Comment: Maybe I havn't formulated my question precisely enough then. What I desire is to have horizontal and vertical gutters always perfectly equals, whatever resizing the page gets.

Comment: Then why not just use *grid-gap: 20px* on the container? That will maintain perfectly equal gutters, vertically and horizontally, in all screen sizes.